# How to setup NodeJS + Socket.io for Digital Ocean deployment

Tags: node.js, socket.io, digital-ocean

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy my node app in Digital Ocean. It's been working fine on my local machine.

I followed a tutorial how to do so and with the sample in that tutorial, I was able to access the site using `pm2 start filename.js`

*123.45.6.78 = Digital Ocean IP address*

```
 var http = require('http');
 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
 }).listen(8080, '123.45.6.78');
 console.log('Server running at http://123.45.6.78:8080/');
```

on my real app I was trying to pattern it like the sample above and also use `pm2 start filename.js`

```
var os = require('os');
var nodeStatic = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');

var fileServer = new(nodeStatic.Server)();
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
   fileServer.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8080, '123.45.6.78');

var io = socketIO.listen(app);
```

It results to `This site can’t be reached 123.45.6.78 refused to connect.`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue, it works on my local machine but not when I deploy it to digitalocean with nginx web server, did the answers solved your problem? or did you do something that solves it?

Answer (score 1):

Digital Ocean by default close all ports except :80

I have already answer the question here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41408983/4556995

Answer (score 0):

Write just listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');